# Some with Webview in Electron

Tags: webview, console, electron, shadow-dom

Is there a way to interact with the browser console to read the console messages?

And the second question is, is there a way to get the HTML code of the page in Webview, at the right time.
Not interaction, but simply load the code to read, then to count the number of elements with a certain class.

It needs to be done some time after the application starts or by pressing the button.

I will be very grateful if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the first part of your question. Please expand on what you are after and also try adding some code that you have tried.

As for the second part of your code you can always do something like this:

```js
function getHtml() {
  return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
}

document.querySelector('#clickme').addEventListener('click', 
  ()=>{
    console.log(getHtml());
  }
);
```

```html
<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
```

`document.documentElement` is the `<html>` element for your page and getting the `outerHTML` of that element will give you all of the current HTML.

Instead of doing a `console.log` you can do what you want with it.

> This will **not** get all of the `shadowDOM`, it will only get the exposed HTML.